# using Spring Security across different webapps

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, web-applications

I'm building a server application **ROOT.war** (containing spring security) and an UI application **viewer.war**.

Is it possible to declare spring security configuration in the **ROOT.war** which will work for the **viewer.war**?

e.g. `intercept-url` in the **ROOT.war:**

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/viewer/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll()"/>
```

I already found a solutions to 'share' the session information between the webapps using hazelcast.

setup:

> / - server webapp, publishing services and providing spring-security
>   /viewer - UI webapp, consuming server services and accessing session data from the server

**Edit**:
I'm sharing the session since it is not possible to access the same session data across two webapps. 
Storing the username in a session in **ROOT** after sucessfull login, will not be available in **/viewer** (could also use a file sessionstore). 
But that is not the question I'm asking. 
I'm wondering if the spring-security filter is used even if another webapp is called **/viewer**, which uses no spring security. Does the spring security configuration from **ROOT** also apply for the **/viewer** webapp?

Flow:

- user requests /viewer in the browser
- spring security from ROOT realize the user is not logged in
- forward to a login page /login
- after sucessfull login, forward to original request /viewer (session holding username)

Comment: AFAIK the answer is no. Every WAR file is a separate application. You don't get any request of another WAR. Moreover, if your root WAR processes the request, your viewer WAR wouldn't get the request, because it is already processed.

Comment: I kind of expected that, so what would be the best-practice for such a scenario? 
Register a servlet filter for /* in /viewer which checks if the user is logged in and forward to /login if not?

Comment: There are some solutions to handle a central authentication: pre authentication with your container (e.g. Tomcat), pre authentication with a proxy (don't authenticate in your applications), OAuth2, CAS, ...,.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to really understand your needs. Spring security is an AOP framework that intercepts requests with filters. Each filter can reject requests based on security rules.

The need for share sessions (on hazelcast, redis or others) comes from case where you have multiple ROOT.war servers, each load balanced, and for each user you don't know where the request goes. The the sessions must be shared across the servers.

I suppose you can allow your client to access to hazelcast sessions, but what is the purpose of this ?

EDIT : I think what do you want is some kind of proxy. You need the requests to go first on ROOT, and if successfully logged, go on VIEWER.

You can do something like this, but all the requests to VIEWER need to pass throught ROOT. And ROOT send the requests to VIEWER.

You can also take other approach like JWT. Generate a JWT from ROOT, and require it on VIEWER.

Comment: The JWT approach sounds like an interesting solution, will have to look deeper into it. How about the suggestion I posted as comment above?

Comment: This approach seems ok to me !
For JWT, I think it's a more costly solution, but it will allow you to really separate ROOT and VIEWER (and to add other applications more easily).